# Flex child gives precedence to max-height over min-height:100%

Tags: css, flexbox

I know that typically min-height takes precedence over max-height. However, I have a flex child with min-height:100% set on it, but it respects its max-height setting instead.

[Here is a codepen demonstrating.](https://codepen.io/jwrudzin/pen/ExMKyjv)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left, .right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 100%; // this is ignored
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
}
```

If I change the min-height to a static value (such as 250px in the Codepen), it respects it. However it doesn't respect it when it's set to 100%, even when its flex sibling (and it's container) grows taller than it does. It also respects the min-height:100% when I set a tall static height on the flex container (such as 400px in the Codepen).

I can't find anything in the spec or anywhere else that explains why the min-height:100% is ignored here, so I'm just looking to understand why this is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but this is what I found.

Firstly, in your case, the calculated height of the parent div , `<div class="wrapper">`, according to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#normal-block), is 0 (case 4). Even when it seems to be 300px because of the child div, `<div class="right"></div>`.

> The element's height is the distance from its top content edge to the
> first applicable of the following:
>
> 1. the bottom edge of the last line box, if the box establishes a inline formatting context with one or more lines
> 2. the bottom edge of the bottom (possibly collapsed) margin of its last in-flow child, if the child's bottom margin does not collapse
>    with the element's bottom margin
> 3. the bottom border edge of the last in-flow child whose top margin doesn't collapse with the element's bottom margin
> 4. zero, otherwise

Hence, using `min-height: 100%` on the left div, evaluates to `min-height: 0`, because it's parent has a implicit calculated height of 0. Translated to code below

```
.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 100%; 
}
```

actually resolves to

```
.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 0; // 100% * 0px  
}
```

That's why the declaration `min-height: 100%` does not overwrite `max-height: 200px` because it's value is 0 and not greater than the value of max-height.

However, when you set explicit heights on either the parent, or min-height, the min-height property overwrites max-height as stated in the [docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)
because now, the value of declaration `min-height: 100%` is greater than that of max-height’s.
.